# Apps get stuck after going to background when I hide/show navbar in ios version less than 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am using this code for hiding the navigation bar in my app so as to keep the pop transition. Everything works fine until my app goes in background. When I come to foreground it gets stuck. I am facing this issue in iOS versions less than iOS10. In iOS10 everything works fine. Anyone faced faced same issue??

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: Did you tried removing this code? I don't think stuck happens because of this.

Comment: You're calling `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` in `viewWillDisappear:`; that could be the issue.

Comment: Yupp removed the code, everything works fine. @venkat

Comment: @Ritu One do not edit out the original code in question. Might be confusing for the ones who read your question later.

Comment: @Venkat I am very sure It is happening because of navigation bar hide and show because if I remove this everything work fine.

Comment: Ok. If you are sure with that, then Create sample app only with navigation bar and the above 2 methods and try. If it happened at this case also. Pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` with `[super viewWillDisappear:animated];` in following code as:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   // [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Damn! It was a copy paste mistake. I have written [super viewWillDisappear:animated]; only.

Comment: Yes, happens every time.

Comment: Also, removing *super* from overridden method is not a good idea. As per Apple Documentation, if you override this method, you must call *super* at some point in your implementation.